# Dart operator + doesn't work

Tags: string, dart, operator-keyword

I read in http://api.dartlang.org/ that there should be a String operator +

***abstract String operator +(String other)***

***Creates a new string by concatenating this string with other.***

For some reason it doesn't work, and Dart says:

"'+' cannot be used for string concatentation".

Have I misunderstood the operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a while the + operator was removed for String. However, this was brought back recently. Make sure that the Dart Editor/SDK that you are using are up to date.

Generally,there are better options than using the + operator for String concatenation. For variables you can use string interpolation:

```
var username = 'Jason';
// ...
var msg = 'Hello ${username}';
```

And for longer Strings concatenation you should use StringBuffer which avoids building the String until you call toString():

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.write("Hello ");
sb.write(username);
var msg = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Dart are you running? This works for me:

```
$ dart --version
Dart VM version: 0.6.3.3_r24898 (Thu Jul 11 07:47:12 2013) on "linux_x64"
$ cat test.dart 
main() {
  print("a" + "b");
}
$ dart test.dart 
ab
```

Comment: Dart Editor version 0.3.5_r18300
 Dart SDK version 0.3.5.1_r18300 . Do you think I need to update it? And how do I check the VM version? Thanks! :)

Comment: Ancient? I just downloaded it a few months ago...! (OK I guess that means ancient). OK, now I've got r24898, and: A. I'm not able to execute anything (looks like it's stuck in an infinite loop) - does it  work only on modern OSs? B. My older programs are suddenly full of errors... I thought that dart was supposed to be "stable" by now!

Comment: A few months ago is ancient in Dartland :) Dart core libraries are stable now, but that wasn't the case for the version you have. Besides, other libraries are not stable, so if you used them there's a good chance of breakage.

Comment: Thanks @PixelElephant. Do the current versions of Dart run only on modern operating systems? Because I updated Dart on my XP (yeah...:P ) and nothing seems to work (not even the simplest code of print("hello world") ), and as the other libraries aren't stable, I don't want to try updating it on other (newer) computers yet...

Comment: The [Dart Editor download page](http://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/) says that only Windows Vista, 7, or 8 are supported, so you may be out of luck with XP.